# Execution plan using index that no longer exist

Tags: sql-server-2014, execution-plan, index-tuning

I have some odd behavior with an execution plan using an index that no longer exists. let me give you the background.

We had some high CPU going on so I had a look what was happening and found a function that was responsible. this function was doing a RID lookup and a table with 200,000,000 records in.  Because of space, we can not just create a clustered index on this table, so I wanted to create a nonclustered covering index for the query.

the query was using a nonclustered index already. So I dropped this index and created my covering index and the function started using it (which is great) CPU came down and all was good.

BUT after a few minutes (and the function fire pretty much every few seconds in working hours) I found that the function was using the old plan (with the index that no longer exists) and CPU went back up.

So I flushed the plan using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (My Plan Handle); 
which worked the function was then using my covering index and the new plan. But again after a few minutes, it started using the old one.

So I mark the function to be recompiled with EXEC sp_recompile N'My function';
again this worked the function was then using my covering index and the new plan. But again after a few minutes, it started using the old one.

Now it's using both and I am stuck with was to try and I'm not sure what is happening?

any advice or pointers would be great.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise (12.0.5546.0)

Comment: There is no possibility to take the pain of creating the clustered index( with compression)?

Comment: Hi, Not at present, I am running a project in the new year to archive data and this table is top of the list. after this is done I can create the clustered index it needs.

Comment: you can try to force the plan

Comment: Odd...  What happens if you reuse the old index name with the new covering index?

Comment: Hi indiri,  If I change the name of the index the query using the new covering index but about 50% of the plan are still using the old one (ie i can still see a RID lookup)